# Format datetime php A.M and P.M

Tags: php

I have it this way AM/PM

I would like to know if the AM / PM format can put a point in between
this is the code that I use

```
$pm =$format->format('d/m/Y H:i:s.00 a.');
```

result A.M or P.M

Answer (score 1):

You can change in below code as per you want.

```
$currentDateTime=date('m/d/Y H:i:s');
$newDateTime = date('h:i A', strtotime($currentDateTime));
echo $newDateTime;
```